# uncaught syntax error

Tags: java

I am using following code for local storage.

```
    for(int i=0; i< files.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("base = " + files[i].getName() + "\n i=" +i + "\n");

            AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(files[i]);
            Tag tag = f.getTag();
            //AudioHeader h = f.getAudioHeader();
            int l = f.getAudioHeader().getTrackLength();
            String s1 = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM);
            out.print("writeToStorage("+s1+","+s1+");");

        }
```

getting uncaught syntex erroe: unexpected identifer as a error.

Comment: Which line is generating an error ?

Comment: `out.print("writeToStorage("+s1+","+s1+");");` this line will be the error.

Comment: @JonTaylor : whats problem with above line?

Answer (score 3):

Im guessing you meant java rather than javascript?

Your unexpected identifier is here `out.println` you need `System.` infront of it.

The reason for this is that *out* is not defined in your code.  You need to access it by using the static variable in the *System* class. Hence why you use `System.out`.

Alternatley you could set a variable out to be equal to System.out for shorthand, although I don;t tend to.  But this can allow you to switch out to a different type of output stream without having to refactor your code much.

Comment: With System.out i am not able to store string in local storage.

Comment: Have you defined out though?  Im not necesserily saying out always has to be System.out but you have to define out somewhere otherwise it will be an unexpected identifier.  The reason it works with System.out for console printing is that out is a static variable defined in the System class.

Comment: I think we are all a little confused as to what exactly you are trying to do.  out needs to point to some form of output stream which allows you to write to it.  This could be to a file etc.  What we don't understand and you need to explain a bit more is what you are trying to do with the method call inside that print statement.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added following ?

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

Comment: probably not otherwise his code would work.  As you can see from his code he is mixing `System.out` and `out` in his two print statements.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to output "s in the last line to surround the s1 values.

"writeToStorage("+s1+","+s1+");"

->

"writeToStorage('"+s1+"','"+s1+"');"

Btw for the same reason you have to fix the other line too:

"base = " + files[i].getName() + "...

->

"base = '" + files[i].getName() + "'...

Comment: why is this necessary? he is just trying to print out the method call (or at least this is what it seems like)

Comment: Because without those the JavaScript code generated will look like:

writeToStorage(something, something);

Where 'something' should be a identifier. What he wants to produce is:

writeToStorage('something', 'something');

Comment: Well this is Java for starters, secondly I have a feeling he just wants to see what the values are and what his method call will look like, but with values instead of variables so he can see it in the console.  Syntactically it is correct and should not cause any problems.

Comment: This is Java producing JavaScript code as it's output. And the error is happening on the client side because the generated JavaScript code is not correct. But if I am completely wrong then just ignore my answer.

Comment: Maybe, maybe I have misunderstood also.  :)